# LINQ complains about different EF contexts used in Service implementing multiple repositories

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a BaseRepository which my repositories inherit. The code is declared as the following:

```
public interface IBaseRepository<T> : where T : class 
{
    IQueryable<T> GetAll();
}

public abstract class BaseRepository<C, T> : IBaseRepository<T>
    where T : class
    where C : DbContext, new()
{

    protected BaseRepository()
    {
        _context = new C();
        _context.Database.Log = message => Trace.WriteLine(message);
    }

    private readonly C _context;
    protected C Context
    {
        get { return _context; }
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return _context.Set<T>();
    }
}

public interface IARepository : IBaseRepository<A>
{
}

public ARepository : BaseRepository<Entities, A>, IARepository
{
}

public interface IBRepository : IBaseRepository<B>
{
}

public ARepository : BaseRepository<Entities, B>, IBRepository
{
}
```

I then have a serivce layer which will be using multiple repositories to fetch data for my controllers.

```
public class SomeService 
{
    private readonly IARepository _aRepository;
    private readonly IBRepository _bRepository;

    public EventService(IARepository aRepository, IBRepository bRepository)
    {
        _aRepository = aRepository;
        _bRepository = bRepository;
    }

    public EventService() : this(new ARepository(), new BRepository())
    {
    }

    public IEnumerable<SomeDTO> GetSomeDTOs()
    {
        return _aRepository.GetAll()
            .Join(_bRepository.GetAll(), a => a.SomeId, b => b.SomeId, (c, d) => new SomeDTO
                {
                    ...
                    ...
                    ...
                }).ToList();
    }
}
```

But here's the problem. I get the following error:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'
>   occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
>
> Additional information: The specified LINQ expression contains
>   references to queries that are associated with different contexts.

when I'm calling the GetSomeDTOs function. From what I can see it should use the same context as it is declared in the baserepository. What seems to be the problem here?

Comment: Ah, `_aRepository` and `_bRepository` have individual context objects. They need to refer to the same one if you want to `Join` them together.

Comment: How'd I do that? The repositories and the services are in a class library which does not have a App.Start where I'd normally use Unity.RegisterComponents();

Comment: Oh, so you do have an IoC container. So, you need to tell it that the context is shared between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that each repository has it's own context, you cannot then join them both together. A simple fix would be to create a shared context and pass that in to your repository:

```
public abstract class BaseRepository<C, T> : IBaseRepository<T>
    where T : class
    where C : DbContext
{

    protected BaseRepository(C context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _context.Database.Log = message => Trace.WriteLine(message);
    }

    //snip
}
```

And create your repositories like this:

```
var context = new MyDbContext();
IARepository aRepository = new ARepository(context);
IBRepository bRepository = new BRepository(context);
```

Comment: Ah, so simple. Thanks a bunch!